# Divergence theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, several-complex-variables

I am revisiting my understanding of integration by parts in several complex variables, but I have run into an apparent contradiction.  This shows my understanding is flawed, which is somewhat embarrassing, but I guess I must fess up and humbly ask for clarification here.  I reproduce the problem specified to one complex variable to make it more generally accessible.

The differential $1$-form $\mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{d}x+i\mathrm{d}y$ on $\mathbb{C}$ eats a complexified tangent vector $a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, and returns the complex number $a+ib$.

Let $r : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function.  Assume that $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : r(z)<0\}$ is smoothly bounded, and that $\nabla r = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$ has length $1$ on the boundary of $\Omega$.  Note that here I am thinking of $\nabla r$ as a "real tangent vector", but these are canonically included in the complexified tangent bundle as well.

Since $\nabla r$ is perpendicular to the boundary of $\Omega$, then by geometry $J(\nabla r) = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial y} - \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ must be tangent to the boundary, where $J$ is the complex structure tensor.  This is also of length $1$, so any real tangent vector to the boundary can be written $v = \alpha J(\nabla r)$.

Noting that $\mathrm{d}S(v) = \alpha$, it seems that we have point wise equalities

$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}z (v) &=  \mathrm{d}z (\alpha J(\nabla r)) \\
&=\alpha \mathrm{d}z \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \frac{\partial }{\partial y} - \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)\\
&=\left( -\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+i\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right) \mathrm{d}S(v)\\
&=2i\cdot \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}S(v)\\
&=2i\frac{\partial r}{\partial \overline{z}} \mathrm{d}S(v)
\end{align*}$

So we can apparently conclude that $\mathrm{d}z = 2i\frac{\partial r}{\partial \overline{z}} \mathrm{d}S$ as $1$-forms on the boundary of $\Omega$ (at least for real tangent vectors which is all we ever plug into either form when integrating something).

Unfortunately, this does not pass the following sanity check.  Let $r(z) = |z|^2-1 = z\bar{z}-1$, so that $\Omega$ is the unit disk.  Then, attempting to use the above identity, we obtain

$
\begin{align*}
\int_{b\Omega} \frac{1}{z} \mathrm{d}z &= \int_{b\Omega} 2i \frac{1}{z} \frac{\partial r}{\partial \overline{z}} \mathrm{d}S\\
&=2i \int_{b\Omega} \mathrm{d}S\\
&=4\pi i
\end{align*}
$

which is a factor of $2$ more than it should be.

I have scoured the above calculations for the $2$ at fault, but have not pinpointed it.  It seems likely to stem from the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of the Wirtinger derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$, but that $\frac{1}{2}$ really does need to be there.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure $r$ has length $1$? I think the $r$ is really $r^2$. Hence, in less awesome notation, $\nabla r = \langle 2x,2y \rangle$ which has length $2$ on $x^2+y^2=1$. Nothing else pops out as wrong except that point, the $r=|z|^2-1$ has $\nabla r$ of non-unit length. So rescale by $2$ and it's spot on.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Ha!  Post it as an answer, this appears to be the source of the confusion.

Comment: What is $dS$? Remember that actually the usual $ds$ is not even a $1$-form :) But your equation $dz = 2i \dots dS(v)$ isn't right, in any event.

Comment: Oh no. Shall I delete the answer...

Comment: @James, I hadn't gotten as far as you had, because I was trying to check the earlier stuff and got confused. But you're absolutely right about the unit disk example.

Comment: @TedShifrin dS is a $1$-form on the boundary defined as the contraction of the volume form by the vector field of unit normals.

Comment: Intuitively, I thought $dS$ would be $d\theta$ for the circle.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook It is.  $dS$ is not a $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it is a $1$-form on a submanifold, defined in the way I indicate above.  In this case, it is equivalent to $d\theta$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you explain why this equation is not correct? Can you pinpoint a flaw in the derivation, or give a counterexample?

Comment: As a $1$-form, it's an oriented arclength measure, all of which we're sloppy about in vector calculus classes. So, by definition, you have $ds = \iota_{\mathbf n}dx\wedge dy$, where $\mathbf n$ is the unit normal to the curve. I was complaining that you said $dz$ (which is still a $1$-form) restricted to the curve was some function times $ds(v)$, which is a function. (I'm referring to your "apparently conclude" sentence.) Much more simply, if $\|dr\|=1$, truly, then your $ds$ is given by $\star dr$, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Whoops.  Meant to write $\mathrm{d}z = 2i\frac{\partial r}{\partial \bar{z}} dS$ as $1$-forms on the boundary.  I agree that $ds = \star dr$.  I generally think in terms of the contraction because that works when the submanifold is not $n-1$ dimensional (just contract an orthonormal frame spanning the complement of the tangent space).  Although I have never gotten very proficient with the use of the Hodge star:  I know I should.  Finally, I should thank you for your book Multivarible Math, which made differential forms make sense to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin  You agree that the updated equation is correct?

Comment: Yes. Let me think a few minutes about a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set $r = \frac{1}{2}(z\bar{z}-1)$. This gives $\nabla r = x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ for which $|\nabla r|=1$ for $|z|^2=x^2+y^2=1$. Then the sanity check works out just fine since $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{z}{2}$ and:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{b\Omega} \frac{1}{z} \mathrm{d}z &= \int_{b\Omega} 2i \frac{1}{z} \frac{\partial r}{\partial \overline{z}} \mathrm{d}S\\
&=i \int_{b\Omega} \mathrm{d}S\\
&=2\pi i.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I will wait to accept your answer until Ted gets back to us.  If he doesn't get back in a few days, I will accept then.

Comment: No problem, I'm curious, did you have a course in several complex variables at some point? If so, what's a good book to read... lately I tinker in calculus of an associative algebra, I will admit, I don't know too much about complex variables in particular...

Comment: I have worked mostly out of Krantz "Function Theory of Several Complex Variables".  I find it to be pretty rough.  Not sure the "best" intro book on SCV has been written yet.  Actually, I have not been able to find the formula I wrote actually written down and proven anywhere in the literature.  It just gets tacitly assumed in the middle of some elaborate IBP calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to avoid evaluating on basis vectors if I can, so here we go: Your hypothesis that $|dr|=1$ tells us that $dr\wedge\star dr = 1 dx\wedge dy = \dfrac i2 dz\wedge d\bar z$. This in turn, by the way, tells us that $\left|\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z}\right| = \dfrac12$ (since $r$ is real-valued). (Simply write out $dr = \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z}dz + \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z$ and use $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial\bar z} = \overline{\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z}}$.)

Now, we've agreed that your desired $ds$ along the level curve $r=0$ should therefore be $\star dr$. So determining the restriction of a $1$-form $\omega$ to a level curve of $r$ is given by determining $\omega \mod{dr}$, i.e., $\omega\wedge dr$. So 
\begin{align*}
dz\wedge dr &= dz\wedge \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z, \text{ whereas} \\
\star dr\wedge dr &= -\frac i2 dz \wedge d\bar z.
\end{align*}
So we conclude that $dz\equiv 2i\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial\bar z}{\star}dr, \mod{dr}$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  This clarifies a lot, and makes the calculation much simpler (especially in the higher dimensional case I was actually interested in).  I will accept @JamesS.Cook 's answer since it actually answers the question I asked.  I wish I could accept all 3!

Comment: Steve, not a problem :) I've spent a lifetime doing differential forms calculations. Hope I can help again.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very satisfying answer, but the defining function for the disk has not been normalized. In fact, its gradient has length two.

Also, I see that James Cook already answered this question.

Comment: I agree. But, Ted has me worried there is more...